# no declaration can be found for element 'cache:annotation-driven'.?

Tags: java, spring, maven, caching

I am trying to make use of Spring-Cache mechanism in my project.

**What I did**
My `applicationContext.xml` looks like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yahoo.comma"/>
    <bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml"/>
        <property name="defaultSchema" value="pryme"/>
    </bean>
    <cache:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- generic cache manager -->
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean" p:name="default"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and in one of my classes I have the following

```
@Cacheable("ages")
@Nonnull
public List<Age> getAges() {
    return ageRepository.findAll();
}
```

When I deploy this using `maven-cargo` plugin, I see failures in logs as

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cache:annotation-driven'.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 16, 2014 10:33:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 16 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 31; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cache:annotation-driven'.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1917) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 26 common frames omitted
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 31; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cache:annotation-driven'.
```

I am not sure even if I have

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
```

why do I have this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your xml is wrong, related to cache schema. It should be:

```xml
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
```